# install electron vs install electron-builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, electron

What's the difference between installing electron alone vs via electron-builder? I'm building an Electron app with React and found a few tutorials already. All of them differ how they install Electron, but there is no explanation why.

[First](https://flaviocopes.com/react-electron/):

```
npx create-react-app app
cd app
npm install electron
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
```

[Second](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c/):

```
create-react-app
npm install --save-dev electron
```

[Third](https://gist.github.com/matthewjberger/6f42452cb1a2253667942d333ff53404):

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn add electron --dev
yarn add electron-builder --dev
yarn global add foreman # for process management
yarn install
```

Two questions:

1. The biggest difference is between First and Second one. In the second tutorial, they didn't even install electron-builder. What's the difference?
2. The second difference is between First and Third: They both installed electron, but one in dev and another not. I'm guessing it should be in `--save-dev`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

The `electron-builder` is a library to build a standalone application for platform os. Suppose you want t build a `.dmg` or `.exe` for your application, you will need `electron-builder`. It is a packaging and distribution thing we need after completing the application. For more information, you can visit [www.electron.build](https://www.electron.build/). You can use `electron-builder` with minimal `configurations` as defined in docs.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for Q1** : To packaging the app to installer or executable application whatever you'd like to be. We can use `Electron-Builder` or `Electron-Package` which is popular and well-known Electron packaging tool. I'd recommend you to have a look at this [How to package the electron app](https://medium.com/how-to-electron/a-complete-guide-to-packaging-your-electron-app-1bdc717d739f)

These `3rd party packaging tools` are just for your app distribution. But you can forward [manual distribution](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution) without using these tools.

The First is the proper way. I think the Second one is the case that is not using 3rd party packaging tools.

**Answer for Q2** : Importing as devDependencies or dependencies won't occur any problem.

But speaking strictly, these should be added as `devDependencies`.

Both `Electron` and `Electron-Builder` is just for needing to build and packaging application. And the production app won't require all of these.

By your question. `I'm guessing it should be in --save-dev. Am I correct?` Yes, exactly